Why is Bash errexit (`set -e`) not passed into command substitution `$()` subshell, but is passed into `()`-subshell
I'm struggling with why an errexit a.k.a. set -e is not passed into a command substitution subshell (invoked with $(my-command) or backticks), but it is passed into a regular subshell (invoked with (my-command)).
This example:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
# or:
#set -o errexit

foo() {
    echo "foo()" >&2

    # Fetch output of actual command, in real life this could be something like
    # and fail because you're not authorized or something
    #somevar=$(curl --fail --silent "restapi.example.com/get-stuff")
    somevar=$(echo foo; exit 42)

    echo "foo() after subcommand, exit code: $?" >&2  # this resets $?
    echo "foo() last exit code: $?" >&2
}

echo '=== Run in $() ===' >&2
a=$(foo)  # runs past this point
echo "code: $?" >&2

echo "=== Run in () ===" >&2
(foo)  # fails
echo "code: $?" >&2

echo "=== Run directly ===" >&2
foo  # fails
echo "code: $?" >&2

this behavior is kinda strange to me because this makes absolutely no sense at all.. to test this even further:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
# or:
#set -o errexit

echo '=== Run 1 ===' >&2
a=$(b=$(exit 42); echo "möp")
echo "code: $?" >&2

# echo '=== Run 2 ===' >&2
# a=$(b=$(exit 43))  # fails without reset of $?
# echo "code: $?" >&2

echo '=== Run 3 ===' >&2
a=$((exit 44); echo "möp")
echo "code: $?" >&2

echo '=== Run 4 ===' >&2
a=$((exit 45))  # works regardless of not resetting $?
echo "code: $?" >&2

# echo '=== Run 5 ===' >&2
# a=$(exit 46; echo "möp")  # fails
# echo "code: $?" >&2

# echo '=== Run 6 ===' >&2
# (exit 47; echo "möp")  # fails
# echo "code: $?" >&2

# echo '=== Run 7 ===' >&2
# ((exit 48); echo "möp")  # fails
# echo "code: $?" >&2

(the out-commented tests would stop the script at this point)
I'd like to know why the thing behaves like this and if this is somehow a bug. I know enough workarounds for this myself and it would probably be smarter to code a few more fail-safes around these commands anyway (especially if this is actually a curl against a REST API where more things could go wrong), but why does bash behave like this?
Tested with

4.4.20
5.2.32


Also see BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?).  (It's doesn't address your problem, but it does explain limitations and problems with set -e that are worth knowing about.)

As with all questions regarding errexit, the answer is "because, reasons".  errexit is a kludge on a hack on a bandaid.  If you have issues with errexit, the correct course of action is to stop using it.

This is a (cross-site) duplicate of Why Bash doesn't pass the errexit option to command substitutions?.

You need shopt -s inherit_errexit for the option to be inherited by command substitutions. See The Shopt Builtin:
inherit_errexit
If set, command substitution inherits the value of the errexit option, 
instead of unsetting it in the subshell environment. This option is 
enabled when POSIX mode is enabled.

